# Insert into database using xmlhttprequest

Tags: php, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want to insert into database using ajax xmlhttprequest the firstname, lastname, email and password with same id and then get all value using getElementById.value and I dont know what is wrong

```js
function loadDoc() {
    var firstname, lastname, email, password;
    firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    lastname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
    email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("hero").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "action.php", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send("firstname=" + firstname "&lastname=" + lastname "&email=" + email "&password=" + password);
}
```

```html
<form>
    firstname:<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"><br>
    Lastname:<input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname"><br>
    Email:<input id="email" type="email" name="email"><br>
    Password:<input id="password" type="password" name="password"><br>
    <input onclickt="loadDoc()" type="button" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<div id="hero"></div>
```

Here is php assign all in the $_POST[""]

```
    $firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
    $lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    if(empty($firstname) || empty($lastname) || empty($email) || empty($password)){
        echo '<h2>Empty Firstname</h2>';
        header("Location index.php");
    } else {
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connection);
        $query = "INSERT INTO user (firstname, lastname, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

        mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $firstname, $lastname, $email, $password);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
    mysqli_close($connection);
```

Comment: where's your action.php code?

Comment: it is so long i cant post here

Comment: thanks for ruining all formatting.

Comment: thank you sir but still i cant save into database

Comment: i put the php sir but it cant insert into database

Comment: you shouldn't fix your code in question, that makes answers meaningless.

Comment: sorry sir i put type= submit  instead of button than you sir

Comment: I am not sir :) just a friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in

```
  xhttp.send("firstname=" + firstname "&lastname=" + lastname "&email=" + email "&password=" + password);
```

change it to

```
  xhttp.send("firstname=" + firstname + "&lastname=" + lastname + "&email=" + email + "&password=" + password);
```

You were missing "+"'s.

Also, another one at "onclickt"

```
<input onclickt="loadDoc()" type="button" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

it should be

```
<input onclick="loadDoc()" type="button" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: and one after `firstname` and `lastname`

Comment: + and & are not the same?

Comment: i put the php sir

Comment: + is concentrate strings in JavaScript, & for parameters in URL. Different things.